# How do I make the listtile change color after return with Navigator.pop()?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, listtile

I am in the process of learning Flutter, but i have run into a problem where my listtile does not want to change the background color after i come back from my  _displaySettingBox function which return a showDialog. It does change to color when i am going back into the _displaySettingBox

The color stored in a list (Listinfonotes) which also content a name (String) and a note (String)

To me is seem that the ListView is not redraw the list of listtile, but there are not any problem when creating (_displayTextInputDialog) and deleting (_displayDeleteBox).

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<ListContent> infonotes = [];

  String? codeDialog = "";
  String? valueText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (codeDialog!.isNotEmpty) {
      ListContent newnote = ListContent(codeDialog!, "", Colors.white);
      infonotes.add(newnote);
      codeDialog = "";
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: infonotes.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            ListContent note = infonotes[index];
            return Card(
              elevation: 10,
              shadowColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: ListTile(
                dense: true,
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 8.0, 16.0, 8.0),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  // side: const BorderSide(width: 2),
                ),
                tileColor: note.color,
                trailing: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.delete_outline,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _displayDeleteBox(context, index);
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 15,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.settings_outlined,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _displaySettingBox(context, index);
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                title: Text(
                  note.name,
                  style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context)
                      .style
                      .apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.5),
                ),
                onTap: () async {
                  final result = await Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return SecondRoute(
                          todo: note.notes,
                          titlename: note.name,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                  // print(result);
                  note.notes = result;
                },
              ),
            );
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _displayTextInputDialog(context);
        },
        tooltip: 'Create note',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

// Setting view
  Future _displaySettingBox(BuildContext context, int index) async {
    // ListContent note = infonotes[index];
    Map<String, Color> colorDict = {
      "White": Colors.white,
      "Red": Colors.red,
      "Green": Colors.green,
      "Blue": Colors.blue,
      "Purple": Colors.purple
    };

    Color dropdownvalue = infonotes[index].color;
    Key testkey = const Key("Red");
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (context, setState) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Settings'),
                content: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    DropdownButton<Color>(
                      // Down Arrow Icon
                      key: testkey,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                      value: dropdownvalue,
                      // Array list of items
                      items: colorDict
                          .map((key, value) {
                            return MapEntry(
                              key,
                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                value: value,
                                child: Text(key),
                              ),
                            );
                          })
                          .values
                          .toList(),
                      // After selecting the desired option,it will
                      // change button value to selected value
                      onChanged: (Color? newValue) {
                        if (newValue != null) {
                          setState(
                            () {
                              dropdownvalue = newValue;
                            },
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: const Text('OK'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        infonotes[index].color = dropdownvalue;
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        });
  }

// delete note viewer
  Future<void> _displayDeleteBox(BuildContext context, int index) async {
    ListContent note = infonotes[index];
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Delete note'),
            content: Text(note.name),
            actions: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.red,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.green,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    infonotes.removeAt(index);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

// create a new note viewer
  final TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();
  Future<void> _displayTextInputDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    _textFieldController.clear();
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Create note'),
            content: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  valueText = value;
                });
              },
              controller: _textFieldController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Note name"),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.red,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: const Text('CANCEL'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                color: Colors.green,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: const Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    codeDialog = valueText;
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}

class ListContent {
  final String name;
  String notes;
  Color color;

  ListContent(
    this.name,
    this.notes,
    this.color,
  );
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  String todo;
  String titlename;

  SecondRoute({super.key, required this.todo, required this.titlename});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text: todo);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(todo),
        ),
        title: Text(titlename),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: controller,
              maxLines: null,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              onChanged: (value) {
                todo = value;
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone who can help me with my problem?